# (SQL server) Get only the dates from datetime format from temp column, convert them to int and put them in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to all of this so I have faced a few problems (i used SQL server only a few times)
I have created new tables to which I have exported data from tables that exist in another database on another server. Everything worked fine. However, in the new tables, I need to use a data type `int` (YYYYMMDD), while this latter is stored as datetime in the original table. I figured I could use a temp table to which I would export the datetime formatted dates and then convert them to in to be put into the date table, but I am sort of stuck right now.

Here is what I have done so far (It contains errors)

```
DECLARE @count int;
SET @count = 0;

DECLARE @NUMOFROWS int;
SET @NUMOFROWS = ( SELECT COUNT(VENTES_CODE_ID) FROM ventes );

WHILE ( @count < @NUMOFROWS )
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Date datetime;
  SET @Date = ( SELECT TEMP FROM ventes WHERE row_number () = @count );

  SELECT into ID_DATE_IDDate AsInteger (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ventese
    WHERE ID_DATE_is NOT LIKE NULL AS rownumber
  ) = CAST( CONVERT( varchar, @Date, 112 ) AS INT );

  @count++;
END
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your query is really strange. Your conditions and equallitys don't make much sense. Can you show us an example of the data on both tables and what the desire result is?

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you can't do the whole set at one time:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable (intcolumn)
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), datecolumn, 112) AS INT)
FROM SourceTable
```

Comment: You gave me the idea of using 
update ventes
set ventes.id_date_id =  CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), temp, 112) AS INT)FROM ventes
it worked!! thanks a lot!!! I really don't know why I went looking for such a complicated idea!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something slightly simpler; create a function to convert both ways so you can convert back and forth at will, and use for the conversion.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DATE2INT ( @date AS DATE ) RETURNS INT AS BEGIN
  RETURN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), @date, 112) AS INT);
END;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION INT2DATE ( @date AS INT ) RETURNS DATE AS BEGIN
  RETURN CONVERT(DATE, CAST(@date AS VARCHAR(32)), 112);
END;
GO

SELECT DBO.DATE2INT(GETDATE());
> 20120312

SELECT DBO.INT2DATE(20120312);
> 2012-03-12

-- Add a month to your integer date
SELECT DBO.DATE2INT(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DBO.INT2DATE(20121212)));
> 20130112
```